# MySQL update two tables where their columns equal that of a row from a third table

Tags: mysql

As the title suggests, I'm trying to use a single query to update multiple rows, in two distinct tables where an id is equal to the result of a select from a third table. Below are sample table layouts.

```
CREATE TABLE hampster_families (
    id INT(13) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    family_name varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    fuzzy_name varchar(255),
    tags varchar(255),
    date_added TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
        PRIMARY KEY (id)

CREATE TABLE apple_addresses (
    id INT(13) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    address VARCHAR(39) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    monitor BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    date_added TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
    hampster_family int(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
        PRIMARY KEY (id)

CREATE TABLE orange_addresses (
    id INT(13) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    address varchar(200) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    monitor BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    date_added TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
    hampster_family INT(7) NOT NULl DEFAULT 0,
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

I'm trying to UPDATE orange_addresses.monitor, apple_addresses.monitor to equal 1, where orange_addresses.hampster_family, apple_addresses.hampster_family equals the id returned from SELECT id FROM hampster_families WHERE hampster_fammilies.family_name = "African Rabid"

I've looked at using a stored variable, but (my lack of SQL prowess shining through here) because this query requires a variable, I don't think a stored variable would work. Given that, I've looked into using a join to accomplish this, but I'm fundamentally misunderstanding the syntax of an UPDATE/JOIN combo. As such, I'm here looking for some enlightenment! :)

Comment: Writing out what the `SELECT` would be helps a lot when constructing joined update statements. Can you make a query like that, or are you having problems with that as well?

Comment: @Wrikken SELECT id FROM hampster_families WHERE family_name = 'African Rabid' LIMIT 1;

Comment: @guedrik: _with_ the join...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step by step:
This is your base query:

```
 SELECT id 
 FROM hampster_families 
 WHERE hampster_fammilies.family_name = "African Rabid"
```

Now, you want all orange_addresses where orange_addresses.hampster_family is that id, so, JOIN:

```
 SELECT hampster_families.id 
 FROM hampster_families
 LEFT JOIN orange_adresses
     ON orange_addresses.hampster_family = hampster_families.id
 WHERE hampster_fammilies.family_name = "African Rabid"
```

The same goes for apple_addresses:

```
 SELECT hampster_families.id 
 FROM hampster_families
 LEFT JOIN orange_adresses
     ON orange_addresses.hampster_family = hampster_families.id
 LEFT JOIN apple_adresses
     ON apple_addresses.hampster_family = hampster_families.id
 WHERE hampster_fammilies.family_name = "African Rabid"
```

We are interested in their monitor columns

```
 SELECT orange_addresses.monitor, apple_addresses.monitor
 FROM hampster_families
 LEFT JOIN orange_adresses
     ON orange_addresses.hampster_family = hampster_families.id
 LEFT JOIN apple_adresses
     ON apple_addresses.hampster_family = hampster_families.id
 WHERE hampster_fammilies.family_name = "African Rabid"
```

Make it an update: move the selected fields after the set, make SELECT FROM an UPDATE:

```
 UPDATE hampster_families
 LEFT JOIN orange_adresses
     ON orange_addresses.hampster_family = hampster_families.id
 LEFT JOIN apple_adresses
     ON apple_addresses.hampster_family = hampster_families.id
 SET 
   orange_addresses.monitor = 1
   apple_addresses.monitor  = 1
 WHERE hampster_fammilies.family_name = "African Rabid"
```

Comment: Superb! Not just the answer, but how to build it from scratch. Bravo!

Comment: Excellent @wrikken! Thank you for not only a solution, but also a step-by-step. I sincerely appreciate your time. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. Just checked.

```
UPDATE orange_addresses, apple_addresses
SET orange_addresses.monitor=1,apple_addresses.monitor=1
WHERE orange_addresses.hampster_family = apple_addresses.hampster_family
    AND orange_addresses.id = (
        SELECT id 
        FROM hampster_families 
        WHERE hampster_families.family_name = 'Test' 
        LIMIT 1);
```

Comment: orange_addresses.id and apple_addresses.id won't be the same. Instead, replace 'id' in the where clause with hampster_family and it works like a charm (did for me).

Comment: My mistake in reading. Thought you wan't to "join" them by `id`, not the `hampster_family` field. ;) Already fixed in my answer